# Angular @Input variable no up to date in an observable (Life cycle)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using a generic component called "genericC" to get some data and send them in an other component as obervable in input to display them.

But, when I try to send a emit of event to this generic component in the goal to update the data, I get a problem because the userId variable which comes from the input of the generic component, is updated only in the ngOnChanges() method.
It's not the case when I use an observable which listen everytime and wait to allow a refresh of data.

Maybe I miss something about the life cycle of data with Angular

This is my code, in hopping, that will be more clear than my previous text:

```
Component A, I want to say, go to update the data via this call : this.uiService.refreshFetchNotify("family");

Component GENERIC:
@Input() userId: string;
@Input() type: string;

..... constructor and declarations of variable

this.refreshFetch$ = this.uiService.refreshFetchChanged().startWith(this.type);

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     // this.userId ===> is up to date as expected
}

this.searchTxt$ = this.searchForm.valueChanges
      .startWith(null)
      .combineLatest(this.refreshFetch$) // this.userId just after is NOT UP TO DATE yet
      .switchMap(([_, refresh]) => {
          if (this.type === 'family' && refresh === this.type)
              return this.filterFamiliesUser(
                this.userId
           );
           else() {
              // something else here
           }
       });
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Edit: In this example, I call it a generic component but even if it's not the case, like now with my application, I use a service, I get also this problem because I continue to use some events which are depending of the @input component

Comment: Things apart, if the generic component doesn't have any view attached and which has a goal to do data updates, could be refactored to a service

Comment: I agree with you, I think I will try to have only a service to avoid the problem mentioned here.

But in the case where I have to keep my component, I would to know the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `valueChanges` will be triggered before `ngOnChanges`.

The `valueChanges` event (which you are currently mapping to `_`) should have the latest value in it.  Use that instead of `this.userId`.  As per the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms):

> An interpolation binding is the easier way to display a name change.
>   Subscribing to an observable form control property is handy for
>   triggering application logic within the component class.

The interpolation binding (e.g. `this.userId`) is intended for the display path.

`valueChanges` is intended for the control path.  You should not combine the two paths.

There are some less optimal solutions as well.

- You could do everything on the `valueChanges` path by adding a `do` to your observable chain which updates `this.userId`.
- You could do everything on the `ngOnChanges` path by creating your own subject and calling `next()` from `ngOnChanges` and never subscribing to `valueChanges`.

However, the optimal solution is simply to use the value changes event itself in the control path and use `this.userId` for display only.

Comment: Thank you for your very constructive answer.

Let me know to clarify some points.

You said: `The valueChanges event (which you are currently mapping to _) should have the latest value in it. Use that instead of this.userId`

I'm not agree with that, I think the `_` represents my searchTxt (It's a text filter) given by a formControl but it's not the problem here. valueChanges is not important in my case.

BTW: The variable `refresh` contains a string that I defined when I emitted my event but it's value isn't important.

Comment: At any moment, I have the `userId` inside my observable that's why I have only the @input of my component to get it.

I think I understand your mistake about the comprehension of my example. When I got the problem, it's only because of the combineLastest which receive a new value emitted by me from an other component via an event. 
Maybe I miss something, in this case, sorry if I don't understand ;)

Comment: I see, I had thought the form control you were watching was the same control that set `this.userId`.  Rather than take `userId` as input can you take the source observable for `userId` as input?